# How to only select contiguous parcels that have same ownership (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, polygon, qgis-3, expression, select

I have a shapefile of a county wide parcel dataset that I'm trying to identify only contiguous parcels that have the same ownership.

In other words, if "Bob Smith" owns a group of contiguous parcels and another parcel that is not 'touching' any other parcels he owns, this parcel is ignored in the selection and only the contiguous group is selected. See example below:

[image]

I'm trying to streamline an internal process in which I simply need to know if an owner has contiguous parcels. I'm using QGIS 3.16.16 Hannover.

I've tried a variety of Select By Attributes, then tried to establish a way to Select By Location, but I'm guessing these tools aren't setup for such logic?  Was hoping someone with similar experience could guide me in the right direction?

Comment: You are selecting them for a reason, if you shared what you want to achieve after you select them, there might be a different approach to the workflow than using Select Layer By ....

Comment: Please decide whether it is ArcGIS Pro or QGIS that you wish to ask about in this particular question. If you tag for Python or one of its libraries then please include a code attempt.

Comment: Your are looking for [Dissolve](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/dissolve.htm)

Comment: With QGIS, use select by expression with this expression: `array_contains (overlay_touches (@layer, name, limit:=-1), name)`

Comment: Thanks Babel, that expression worked perfectly! Thanks for understanding that I was looking for the best solution, either ArcGIS Pro or QGIS. Thanks for understanding that I didn't need to provide a sample python script (being new to it) even though I tagged it, because it could also have been a solution that someone could have pointed me to. Great to have folks who can look outside of the box and not just closing my question.

Comment: Question was reopened and I could add it as an answer. For that I changed your question to QGIS. Be aware that due to the policy of this site, questions that ask for several software packages at once (like QGIS **or** ArcGIS) get closed. So technically, the expectation would be to ask two separate (mostly identical) questions for QGIS and the other for ArcGIS (you might make a link between them). Just to understand why your question got closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With QGIS, to make a selection only of contiguous parcels that have the same owner (attribute `name`), use [Select by expression](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html#automatic-selection) with this expression:

`array_contains (overlay_touches (@layer, name, limit:=-1), name)`

To speed up the expression, you could set `limit:=-1` to a positive number: the maximal number of direct (touching) neighbors for each polygon. A numer of 3 or 4 should be OK for cases like the one in the screenshot below.

*See here to understand the two functions involved: [overlay_touches()](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#overlay-touches) and [array_contains()](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#array-contains)*

[image]