# Select contiguous area with the same value in column "name" in PostgreSQL (PostGIS)

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have a table `parcel` with the fields
`parcel_id`, `parcel_polyid` and `parcel_owner`.
Further, I have a table `polygons` with the fields `polyid` and `shape` the latter being of type *geometry*.

I want to select all the parcels that are contiguous to each other and have the same parcel_owner. Basically a duplicate of the [following](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/438992/how-to-only-select-contiguous-parcels-that-have-same-ownership-qgis) except that I need it in PostgreSQL and not in QGIS.

So far I've got:

```
select parcel_id
from parcel
join polygons 
on parcel_polyid = polyid
where ST_Intersects(polygons.shape,polygons.shape) and parcel_owner = parcel_owner
```

Unfortunately, this returns all the parcels. I think because it checks the intersection and entry with itself.

Comment: Try to `GROUP BY "parcel_owner"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a job for the mighty [`ST_ClusterDBSCAN`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ClusterDBSCAN.html); as a *Window function* it operates on (value bounded) partitions of input *rows* rather than generating an aggregated spatial predicate join result-set.

With an `eps` parameter of `0` (or a tiny distance threshold), you essentially cluster by intersection.

Run:

```
SELECT
  pcl.parcel_id,
  pcl.parcel_owner,
  ST_ClusterDBSCAN(ply.shape, 0, 1) OVER(PARTITION BY pcl.parcel_owner) AS cluster_id,
  ply.shape
FROM
  parcels AS pcl
  JOIN
  polygons AS ply
    ON pcl.parcel_polyid = ply.polyid
;
```

An individual cluster can be uniquely identified by `parcel_owner` + `cluster_id`, e.g. to aggregate per cluster you'd need to `GROUP BY parcel_owner, cluster_id`.

Comment: Thanks! 

So far, your command returned no error but also no result. There are contigous parcels with the same owner though. 
I will look into ST_ClusterDBSCAN and Group by but maybe I won't be able to do that today. Perhabs I will have a follow up question tomorrow or in a couple of days.

Comment: "No result" as in _no rows at all_? Or do you not get any `cluster_id`s? In the former case, check the exact naming and the join condition, this is unrelated to the clustering and a simple syntax issue most likely. In the latter case, try a tiny `eps` distance threshold, e.g. `0.0001` if your CRS is in *degrees*.

Comment: I had no rows at all due to a typo. Your solution works very well. I didn't have to change the eps distance. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Your current query returns all parcels because `ST_Intersects(polygons.shape,polygons.shape) and parcel_owner = parcel_owner` takes each line and check if the geometry intersects with *itself* and if the owner is equal to *itself*

I have come up with this solution which works. I post it even though there's a much more elegant answer already. But it has the benefits of showing how to come up with a solution without advanced SQL knowledge.

In short it creates two similar temporary tables `t1` and `t2`, which have the whole parcel/geometry list (simple select on both `parcel` and `polygon` tables `where parcel.parcel_polyid=polygons.poly_id`.

And then it join these two tables on:

- geometries intersect: `st_intersects(t1.geometry,t2.geometry)`
- owner is the same: `t1.owner=t2.owner`
- and that parcel is not itself: `t1.parcel_id != t2.parcel_id`

```sql
select t1.parcel_id, t1.owner, t1.geometry from 

(select parcel.parcel_id,parcel.owner,parcel.parcel_polyid,polygons.geometry, polygons.poly_id
   from parcel parcel, polygons polygons 
   where parcel.parcel_polyid=polygons.poly_id) t1

 join 
 
 (select parcel.parcel_id,parcel.owner,parcel.parcel_polyid,polygons.geometry, polygons.poly_id
   from parcel parcel, polygons polygons
   where parcel.parcel_polyid=polygons.poly_id) t2 
 
 on st_intersects(t1.geometry,t2.geometry)
 and t1.parcel_id != t2.parcel_id and t1.owner=t2.owner
```

This returns a table with all parcels (id,owner, associated geometry) which have overlapping polygons with other parcels having the same owner.

Parcel areas, not overlapping each other:
[image]

Parcel areas highlighted when similar owner have intersecting geometries:
[image]

Parcel areas with intersecting geometries but not the same owner are not highlighted:
[image]