# How to only select contiguous parcels that have the same ownership AND exclude those owners that have parcels that are non-contiguous (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, parcel, select-by-expression

I have a shapefile containing parcel data for multiple counties, and I'm trying to narrow this dataset with the following conditions:

1.) Identify owners with contiguous parcels
AND
2.) Exclude owners that may have contiguous parcels, but may also have parcels that are not contiguous.

I followed this question and found it extremely helpful [How to only select contiguous parcels that have same ownership (QGIS)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/438992/how-to-only-select-contiguous-parcels-that-have-same-ownership-qgis)

which gives the following select by expression formula:

```
array_contains (overlay_touches (@layer, name, limit:=-1), name)
```

I was able to select those owners with contiguous parcels, but now I want to narrow the results further to only owners with contiguous parcels and no other parcels. For example, if John Doe is in my table and owns 5 parcels, and 3 are touching (those three are selected under the current expression), I want to remove John Doe from my table completely.

Answer (score 1):

Collect all geometries with the same name, buffer them by 0 (to dissolve), then check if the result is multipart. To do so, use this expression:

```
not is_multipart( 
    buffer (
        with_variable (
            'nm',
            name,
            collect( $geometry, filter:=name=@nm)
        ),0
    )
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Run Menu <kbd>Processing</kbd> > <kbd>Toolbox</kbd> > <kbd>[Aggregate](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgisaggregate)</kbd> and select the `owner` field for `Group by expression`.
2. Run the expression `not is_multipart( $geometry)` on the aggregated layer.

Comment: Thanks for your response - I could not get the multipart_buffer with_variable code below to run on my computer, however, I was able to follow your suggestions for aggregating the layer. However, when I attempt the ` not is_multipart ($geometry)` on the aggregated layer, QGIS says that no features were selected. I don't get any error message beyond that.

Comment: Replace `name` with the name of your `owner` field.

Comment: Gotcha, I tried that, but still get the eternal spin.

Comment: Probably too many data, QGIS repeats this for every feature. Stick to this solution here using aggregate

Comment: Any idea why the expression: not is_multipart($geometry) would return 0 features on the aggregated layer?

Comment: Difficult to say. Can you share sample data?

Comment: Yes, I just added a screenshot to the bottom of my post with names/addresses edited. For reference, I also used multipart function after using the dissolve tool to see if it would work, and it also did not. There's a few more columns that got cut from the screeenshot (simply so I didn't have to censor them) like lat/long, city, county, etc.

Comment: A simple table does not help, you should post actual data, including the geometries. Otherwise, it's impossible to see what went wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this, I apologize. Thanks for your help thus far. If you could explain how I could give you an example of this data (without identifying information) I would appreciate it. Otherwise, I understand if you are tapping out here.

Comment: You can upload it to any cloud service and share the link here.